# Deserealizar un .json en vb.net con Json .Net

Tags: json, vb.net, visual-studio

no soy muy experto utilizando la libreria NewtonSoft en Visual Basic. Net... Quiero deserealizar la siguiente cadena JSON, para luego mostrar los datos en TextBoxes en orden descendente ejemplo(primero los datos de Martin, luego Angel etc...)

```
{
    "Personal": [
        {
            "nombre": "Martin",
            "apellido": "Scarpini"
            "correo": "martin.scar2130@hotmail.com"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "Angel",
            "apellido": "Velazquez",
            "correo": "angel3001.velazquz@hotmail.com"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "Jose",
            "apellido": "Perez",
            "correo": "perezjose2@hotmail.com"
        },

    ]
}
```

Alguien que me pueda ayudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero debes de crear las clases que se acoplen al **json** que recibes.

Basándome en el **json** que dejas en la pregunta las clases que deberías crear serian:

```
Public Class PersonalViewModel
    Public Property Personal As List(Of PersonaViewModel)
End Class

Public Class PersonaViewModel
    Public Property nombre As String
    Public Property apellido As String
    Public Property correo As String
End Class
```

> Nota: Los nombres de las clases le puedes asignar el que se acople a tus necesidades, en el ejemplo que te dejo las llame **`PersonalViewModel`** y **`PersonaViewModel`**.

Una vez agregada la referencia del **Newtonsoft** solo debes importar el espacio de nombre `Newtonsoft.Json`:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
```

Ahora procedes a llamar al método `DeserializeObject` de la clase `JsonConvert`:

```
Dim viewModel As PersonalViewModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of PersonalViewModel)(strJson)
```

> Nota: la variable **`strJson`** la reemplazas por la variable que contiene tú json.

Comment: Bien, ahora otra duda... como haria para mostrar los datos en un Textbox?

Comment: No se como quieres presentar esa informacion en Textbox ya que no das muchos detalles. Creo que lo mejor es que crees una nueva pregunta expresando el inconveniente que tienes para colocar la data en los Texbox y con gusto la comunidad te ayudara.